# Am I using .done() Wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an app where I want to get data from an API using `.getJSON()` and store it in an Array, but I don't want to move forward with the code until the array is fully loaded, so I've invoked the `.done()` method, but my code continues to move forward with the array before it is full defined, leading to undefined errors. Here is the relevant code:

```
var similarList  = getSimilar(randArtist, year);
        similarList.done(function(item){
            for (var j=0, len=similarList.length; j<len; j++){
            similarArtistDict[similarList[j].name] = 
similarArtistDict[similarList[j].name] || true;
        }
```

the `getSimilar` function should return a list, thus defining the variable similarList. Instead, the code moves directly onto the for loop despite my done call, leading to an exception when the loop tries to get `similarList.length`.

EDIT PART 2: A stripped down version of my getSimilar method for reference. I realized the function itself was not returning anything, so I tried to return the AJAX call itself -- that did not return an array. How could I tweak this function to return the array data.artists?:

```
function getSimilar(name, year){
    $.getJSON(ECHONEST_SIMILAR_URI, {
            api_key: ECHONEST_KEY,
            name: name,
            artist_start_year_before: year,
            results: '5'

    }, function(response){
         var data = response.response;
         console.log(data);
         console.log(data.artists);
         return data.artists;
    } ); }
```

Comment: What does the getSimilar function return, exactly?

Comment: We have no idea what `getSimilar` is doing.

Comment: It calls an API with getJSON() and returns a list with data from the call. It's kind of an involved method, but I've tested it up to its return point and it should be returning the list value, so I thought my problem had to do with the done() call.

Comment: Well your problem is in there and you are not showing it, but I'm guessing you are implementing your ajax improperly.

Comment: Okay, I added the method. The final console.log of the method returns exactly what I need, a list of artists.

Comment: What is `similarList` supposed to be? The function's argument is named `item`. Btw, your `getSimilar` snippet is missing a `return`, maybe you should provide a non-stripped-down version.

Comment: Okay, I think I isolated my problem. The function wasn't returning anything. But I'm still not sure how I could get it to return an array object. See EDIT 2.

Comment: I wish you had titled this question "What have I .done() wrong?"

Answer (score 1):

I think I can guess where you are going wrong.

I'm assuming your `getSimilar` function looks like

```
function getSimilar(a,b){
    var arr;
    $.get("test.php").done(function(val) {
        arr = val;
    });
    return arr;
}
```

If so, you are forgetting that AJAX means Asynchonous.
You want to put a call back function in to execute after the request is complete.

Try something like this instead.

```
function getSimilar(a,b){        
    $.get("test.php").done(function(val) {
        GetListCallback(val);
    });
}
function GetListCallback(val){
    for (var j=0, len=similarList.length; j<len; j++){
        similarArtistDict[similarList[j].name] = similarArtistDict[similarList[j].name] || true;
}
```

Comment: No, his `getSimilar` function returns a jQuery promise, otherwise the `done()` call would not have worked.

Comment: As far as I can tell getSimilar doesn't return anything. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that's true for the code he posted (I assume he stripped it down too much). However, he reported to have the `similarList.done()` executed successfully.

Comment: I was thinking he just put a breakpoint in his anonymous done function and that would occur after the getSimilar function already returned.

Comment: OK, it seems he really has not understood what the A means.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return the array from the `getSimilar` function, since it is fetched asynchronous and will not yet be available when the function returns. However, you can return the promise for the result of the asynchronous-jax call, and [pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) it to result in the array (in recent versions of jQuery it's the `then` method):

```
getSimilar(randArtist, year).done(function(similarList) {
    for (var j=0, len=similarList.length; j<len; j++) {
        similarArtistDict[similarList[j].name] = similarArtistDict[similarList[j].name] || true;
    }
});
function getSimilar(name, year){
    return $.getJSON(ECHONEST_SIMILAR_URI, {
            api_key: ECHONEST_KEY,
            name: name,
            artist_start_year_before: year,
            results: '5'

    }).then(function(response){
         var data = response.response;
         console.log(data);
         console.log(data.artists);
         return data.artists;
    });
}
```

Comment: Even after adding the then pipe, I'm still getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined.

Comment: Did you add the `return` as well?

Comment: But then you won't get the above error; try to `console.log` the object that `getSimilar` returns.

Comment: The closest I can get to logging it is logging data.artists right before the return statement, since the getSimilar function seems to be returning undefined. But if I do console.log(data.artists), it gives me an array of Artist objects -- exactly what I want it to return.

Comment: `data.artists` is not what `getSimilar` returns, but what the `then` mapper function will return! Could you please log the `similarList` from your original code (while using my `getSimilar` function)?

Comment: How would I get getSimilar to return the array, because that's what I need it to do? console.log(getSimilar(randArtist, year)) returns undefined, and using the .done() method on it raises the above error.

Comment: Have a look at the first sentence of my answer. Not sure why `getSimilar` returns undefined for you; which jQuery version do you use?

Comment: I use version 1.9.1. I get that getSimilar is asynchronous, but my understanding was that what was piped through .then() would be returned if I invoked the .done() method. What I need is access to the data.artists array in my other function that calls the AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, then it should work. See [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/eBZAE/) to test various jQuery versions.